# Microsoft Azure hostname didn't match

Tags: android, azure, azure-devops, azure-cognitive-services, minix

I am using Microsoft Azure Face to get the data from an image in an Android Application running in an android box (minix), when I reach the point in the code where I send the image to receive this data I get the following error:

Detection failed: hostname in certificate didn't match:  != <*.cognitiveservices.azure.com> OR <*.cognitiveservices.azure.com>

I don't know what this error means because I am not using the certificates.
The base code I am using is the one from the original repository:

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-face-android-detect

Note: If i run this code in an Android mobile it works correctly but the objective is to make it work in the android box (minix).

Note2: I have a valid suscription key.

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this a few months ago so I'm posting the solution I found.

The problem was due to "okhttp" library, after talking with the Azure developers they told me to update the version to "1.4.4" from "1.4.3".
After that I had a problem with the said library "okhttp":

> Failed to transform file 'okhttp-3.13.1.jar' to match attributes
>   {artifactType=android-dex, dexing-is-debuggable=true,
>   dexing-min-sdk=15} using transform DexingTransform Error while dexing.

I also solved this problem following JakeWharton's answer in this post from github

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/4597

So I had to add the following lines in my application "build.gradle" :

```
 compileOptions {
        targetCompatibility = "8"
        sourceCompatibility = "8"
    }
```

I hope this helps someone with the same situation as me.